# magit function to check if a branch is in sync with remote

Tags: magit

Is there a function in magit to check if a branch is in sync with with it's remote (basically I want to check if both branches sit on the same commit)

At the moment I check if remote branch and the local one are sitting on the same commit, but maybe there is something I could not find yet inside magit already?

```
(s-equals? (magit-rev-parse (magit-get-current-branch))
           (magit-rev-parse (magit-get-push-branch)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't take you all the way, but `magit-rev-eq` helps here:

```
(magit-rev-eq (magit-get-current-branch)
              (magit-get-push-branch))
```